# My widget's css is computed differently on different website

Tags: html, css, widget

I've developed a widget that insert the dynamic html into a div of a host website. The widget's html and css it's loaded in the host page, it's not into an iframe.

Here's the widget that load correctly on my website http://crocofan.com and here's the widget on a user's website http://www.mylittlechickblog.com (wait 20 second to make it appears).

You can see the wrong width and height of the widget's white box and that the "X" symbol in the top right corner is not shown correctly.

What can I do to make it show correctly on this website and in general on every website?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple problems. One:

```html
<div id="text-17" class="widget widget_text">
```

has `overflow: hidden`, which is why the "x" is cut off. I think if you do this:

```css
#cfwContainer { overflow: visible !important; }
```

it will work.

The second issue is that `box-sizing: border-box` is set on all the elements on the second page. If you set `box-sizing: content-box` explicitly on all your widget elements, it will keep everything sized.